# getIntent returning null

Tags: java, android

In android when I try to use the getIntent(); method in android, it returns null,which is causing the application to crash. Here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.mycompany.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText textbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = textbox.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message.toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This first activity calls the second:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Intent intent = getIntent();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_mesage);

        String message = "";

        if (intent == null) {
            Log.d("Intent", "Intent is null :(");
        }

        try {
            message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Message", "Message is null");
        }


        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(message);
        textView.setTextSize(40);

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
        layout.addView(textView);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it returns null, since I call it myself using an intent that... is not null.

EDIT : I also tried to use something else than a constant for the key, like "message", rather than EXTRA_MESSAGE, it leads to the same result.

Comment: Move `Intent intent = getIntent();` inside `onCreate` method

Comment: Oooh... thanks. That's something I was used to doing in C#, didn't know it wouldn't work here. Thank you very much.

Comment: It doesn't work there because any statement outside of a method like that occurs at initialization time-  when the object is created, before the constructor is called.  At that time an Intent hasn't been passed to the object yet.  Really you should only use initializers like that for simple values (like 1,2, "hello", etc) or to create objects with new.  You shouldn't call functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two causes of null .
1) if you had not declared activity in manifest.xml file in andorid .
2) You must use getIntent() inside oncreate() method ,the code for that thing is here :-

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_mesage);

        Intent intent = getIntent();


        String message = "";

        if (intent == null) {
            Log.d("Intent", "Intent is null :(");
        }

        try {
            message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Message", "Message is null");
        }


        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(message);
        textView.setTextSize(40);

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
        layout.addView(textView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**getIntent()** method must be called after the **setContentView()** method

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_mesage);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = "";

    if (intent == null) {
        Log.d("Intent", "Intent is null :(");
    }

    try {
        message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Message", "Message is null");
    }


    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText(message);
    textView.setTextSize(40);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
    layout.addView(textView);
}
```

}

Comment: Why must getIntent() be called after setContentView()?

Comment: Oh, so you can findViewById()! I'm pretty sure you can get the intent before that.