# Varible is always null when using android studio put extra

Tags: java, android

The variable I am trying to send is instantiated at the top of the code and assigned its array values further down.

```
Intent subject_and_grades = new Intent(main_questionnaire.this, subject_and_grades.class);      //if there are no errors display the next page
subject_and_grades.putExtra("user_inputs", user_inputs);
startActivity(subject_and_grades);
```

But in the next class the variable is always null.

```
Intent extras = getIntent();
String Student_Attributes = extras.getStringExtra("user_inputs");
```

here is the code of the first activity, the variable is first initialised right at the top of the code, then its values are added further down.

```
public class main_questionnaire extends AppCompatActivity {

    String [] user_inputs;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_questionnaire);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        final TextView error_display = findViewById(R.id.error_display);


        Button page_2 = findViewById(R.id.page_2);
        page_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String age = "17";
                String Pstatus = "1";                //due to the fact i don't want to enter all the text fields every time i
                String address = "1";                // test the code, i hardcoded in the attributes for testing.
                String Medu = "4";
                String Fedu = "4";
                String traveltime = "1";
                String studytime = "3";
                String schoolsup = "0";
                String activities = "1";
                String higher = "1";
                String absences = "4";
                String qualification = "1";


                //so we can iterate through all the user inputs

                int lower_bound[] = {0, 0, 0, 15, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};        //validation range for each text field from 0
                int upper_bound[] = {4, 4, 1, 22, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 93, 1, 1};

                user_inputs = new String[]{Medu, Fedu, Pstatus, age, traveltime, studytime, schoolsup, address, activities, absences, higher, qualification};


                //all the ids for all the warnings above the text views
                String warning_ids[] = {"Text_View_Warning_1", "Text_View_Warning_2", "Text_View_Warning_3", "Text_View_Warning_4", "Text_View_Warning_5",
                        "Text_View_Warning_6", "Text_View_Warning_7", "Text_View_Warning_8", "Text_View_Warning_9", "Text_View_Warning_10",
                        "Text_View_Warning_11", "Text_View_Warning_12"};



                //this loop iterates over all the answer and calls a function that validates them
                for (int i = 0; i < user_inputs.length; i++) {
                    int error_writer_answer;
                    error_writer_answer = error_writer(warning_ids[i], user_inputs[i], lower_bound[i], upper_bound[i]);
                    if (error_writer_answer > 0) {                                  //checks to see if the error counter has counted any errors
                        error_display.setText("Errors above: " + error_writer_answer);                //print the number of errors the user has got at the bottom of the page
                    } else {
                        if (i == user_inputs.length-1) {
                            Intent subject_and_grades = new Intent(main_questionnaire.this, subject_and_grades.class);      //if there are no errors display the next page
                            subject_and_grades.putExtra("user_inputs", user_inputs);
                            startActivity(subject_and_grades);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

second page code

```
package com.example.smartrevisionschedule2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.chaquo.python.PyObject;
import com.chaquo.python.Python;
import com.chaquo.python.android.AndroidPlatform;

public class subject_and_grades extends AppCompatActivity {



    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String[] array = bundle.getStringArray("user_inputs");
```

Comment: did you checked type and value of user_input?

Comment: the type is a string array, would that be fine with .getStringExtra ?

Comment: no it's not fine. you should use extras.getStringArrayExtra()

Comment: @taylor_brierley checkout the updated answer.

Comment: @rahat the variable is still null

Comment: @taylor_brierley can you add your updated code of the second activity.

Comment: @rahat just did

Comment: @rahat I'm getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: Please add error stack trace

Comment: @taylor_brierley please see my answer below, I getting data from intent in `onCreate`, not while it is declared. please follow the answer and if it does not work let me know.

Comment: @rahat yep that worked, it was just because it wasn't below the on create, thanks a lot.

Comment: @rahat I cant upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use get method appropriate your put.

If you put StringArray, you should use getStringArrayExtra() method.

```
String[] Student_Attributes = intent.getStringArrayExtra("user_inputs");
```

Please check your put type and get methods.

**PS:**

You can use Bundle for transfer data between two activities.

When put:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArray("user_inputs", user_inputs);
Intent intent=new Intent(main_questionnaire.this, subject_and_grades.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

When get:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
String[] array = bundle.getStringArray("user_inputs");
```

**PS**

You should put getIntent() code in onCreate() method instead Activity class directly.

So you need like this.

```
public class subject_and_grades extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ..............

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String[] array = bundle.getStringArray("user_inputs");
    }
}
```

Comment: it's still null, I added the code from the first activity.

Comment: Updated answer. Please try with Bundle.

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: Yep, it didn't work it actually returned a null pointer exception on Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); when I put that in the other class.

Comment: did you put getIntent() code in onCreate method? seems to getIntent() returns null.

Comment: I updated my answer. And please refer this URL. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38171443/10247147

Comment: what is the activity flag? if activity is singTop or singleInstance, it will cause error in some case.

Comment: how do I check that ?

Comment: Why is it necessary that it is below on create

Answer (score 0):

Since you are putting a string array you must retrieve a string array

Your current code to get data, the very line will change as follows.

```
public class subject_and_grades extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent extras = getIntent();
    String[] Student_Attributes = extras.getStringArrayExtra("user_inputs");
```

will be

```
public class subject_and_grades extends AppCompatActivity {
    String[] Student_Attributes;

    @Override
     public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)
       Intent extras = getIntent();
       String[] Student_Attributes = extras.getStringArrayExtra("user_inputs");
     }
```

Comment: it still equals null.

Comment: @taylor_brierley can you add the code of your first activity

Comment: @taylor_brierley, I just check it. the array received in the next activity, can you add the code of the next activity.

Comment: just added it, there is more code below but that's the relevant part

Comment: @taylor_brierley answer is here

Answer (score 0):

You should use `putStringArrayListExtra()` instead of `putExtra()`. But you have to convert your `user_inputs` into list of strings first by `List<String> list = Arrays.asList(user_inputs);`.

```
Intent subject_and_grades = new Intent(main_questionnaire.this, subject_and_grades.class);
subject_and_grades.putStringArrayListExtra("user_inputs", Arrays.asList(user_inputs));
startActivity(subject_and_grades);
```

Later, you can retrieve `user_inputs` by calling `getStringArrayListExtra()`.

```
Intent extras = getIntent();
List<String> Student_Attributes_List = extras.getStringArrayListExtra("user_inputs");
for(String Student_Attributes : Student_Attributes_List) {
     //Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variable "user_inputs" you have is a StringArray then you cant use the putString() and getStringExtra() combination, instead it has to be .putStringArrayListExtra() and .getStringArrayExtra() or better yet .getStringArrayListExtra() actually. If you have other formats for the variable then it would be a really good idea to putExtra the variable as a Parcel